# How to display a select with another select?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, twig, symfony4

I would like to display the field form.childNumber and form.childFoyerFiscal according to the answer of form.child

If the person chosen TRUE : 
-- Display"enfantNombre" and "enfantFoyerFiscal"

If the person chosen is FALSE: 
- Do not display anything

All this must change without refreshing the page (with AJAX for example)

Something like that : 
[image]

```
class SimulationType extends AbstractType



public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        /* Partie 1 - Situation */
        ->add('situationFamilliale', ChoiceType::class,$this->getConfigurationChoice("Votre situation familliale ?", "input"))
        ->add('anneeDeNaissance', IntegerType::class,$this->getConfigurationInteger("Quelle est votre année de naissance ?", "input"))
        ->add('enfant', ChoiceType::class,$this->getConfigurationBoolean("Avez vous des enfants ?", "radioButton"))
        ->add('enfantNombre', IntegerType::class,$this->getConfigurationInteger("Combien avez-vous d'enfants ?", "input"))
        ->add('enfantFoyerFiscal', IntegerType::class,$this->getConfigurationInteger("Combien sont encore dans votre foyer fiscal ?", "input"))
        ->add('pension', ChoiceType::class, $this->getConfigurationBoolean("Payez vous une pension ?", "radioButton"))
        ->add('pensionPrix', IntegerType::class, $this->getConfigurationInteger("Combien vous coûte cette pension mensuellement?", "input"))

        /* Partie 2 - Patrimoine */
        ->add('residencePrincipale', ChoiceType::class, $this->getConfigurationResidence("Concernant votre résidence principale vous êtes :", "radioButton", "Proprietaire", "Locataire", "Heberge gratuitement"))
            // Propriétaire
            ->add('creditResidencePrincipale', ChoiceType::class, $this->getConfigurationBoolean("Avez-vous un crédit sur la résidence principale ?", "radioButton"))
                // Propriétaire -> Oui
                ->add('proprietaireCreditPrix', IntegerType::class, $this->getConfigurationInteger("Combien vous coûte ce crédit par mois ?", "input"))
                ->add('proprietaireCreditTemps', IntegerType::class, $this->getConfigurationInteger("Quelle est la durée restante (en année) ?", "input"))
            //Locataire
            ->add('locataireCreditLoyer', IntegerType::class, $this->getConfigurationInteger("Quel est la montant de votre loyer /mois ?", "input"))

        //Investissement Locatif
        ->add('investissement_bis', ChoiceType::class, $this->getConfigurationBoolean("Avez-vous déjà un investissement locatif en cours ?", "radioButton"))
            //Investissement Locatif -> Oui
            ->add('investissement', CollectionType::class, ['entry_type' => InvestissementType::class, 'allow_add' => true]) // Créer les différents investissements

        // Credit (Autres qu'immobilier)
        ->add('credit', ChoiceType::class, $this->getConfigurationBoolean("Avez-vous des crédits? (Autres qu'immobilier)", "radioButton"))
            //Credit (Autres qu'immobilier) --> Oui
            ->add('creditAdd', CollectionType::class, ['entry_type' => CreditType::class, 'allow_add' => true])
        ->add('revenuMensuel', IntegerType::class, $this->getConfigurationInteger("Quel est le revenu net MENSUEL de votre foyer ?", "input"))

        /* Partie 3 - Epargne */
        ->add('epargne', ChoiceType::class, $this->getConfigurationEpargne("A combien estimez-vous votre épargne?", "radioButton", "Moins de 10.000€", "Entre 10.000€ et 20.000€", "Entre 20.000€ et 50.000€", "Entre 50.000€ et 100.000€", "Plus de 100.000€"))
        ->add('apportInvestissement', ChoiceType::class, $this->getConfigurationBoolean("Envisagez vous de mettre un apport dans votre investissement?", "radioButton"))
            // qpportInvestissement -> Oui
            ->add('apportPrix', IntegerType::class, $this->getConfigurationInteger("Combien apporteriez-vous ?", "input"))
        ->add('reductionImpot', ChoiceType::class, $this->getConfigurationBoolean("Avez-vous déjà des réductions d'impôts ?", "radioButton"))
            // reductionImpot -> Oui
            ->add('reductionImpotPrix', IntegerType::class, $this->getConfigurationInteger("De combien réduisez vous votre impôt par an ?", "input"))

        /* Partie 4 - Objectifs */
        ->add('objectifsPrincipaux', ChoiceType::class, $this->getConfigurationObjectifsPrincipaux("Choisissez vos 3 objectifs principaux", "radioButton", "input", "input1", "input2", "input3", "input4", "input5", "input6"))
        ->getForm();

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Client::class,
    ]);
}




/**
 * Permet d'avoir la configuration de base d'un IntegerType
 *
 * @param string $label
 * @param string $class
 * @return array
 */
private function getConfigurationInteger($label, $class){

    return  [
        'label' => $label,
        'attr' =>[
            'class' => $class
            ],
        'required' => true
    ];
}



/**
 * Permet d'avoir la configuration de base d'un button de type RADIO
 *
 * @param string $label
 * @param string $class
 * @return array
 */
private function getConfigurationBoolean($label, $class): array
{
    return [
        'label' => $label,
        'attr' =>[
            'class' => $class
        ],
        'choices' => [
            'Oui' => true,
            'Non' => false,
        ],

        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false,
    ];
}


/*
* Permet d'avoir le choix en plusieurs proprositions (Max 5)
* L'utilisation de cette function peut servir quand il y a plusieurs choix à faire.
*
*/
public function getConfigurationObjectifsPrincipaux($label, $class, $choix1, $choix2, $choix3, $choix4, $choix5, $choix6, $choix7): array
{
    return [
        'label' => $label,
        'attr' =>[
            'class' => $class
        ],
        'choices' => [
            $choix1 => "patrimoineImmobilier",
            $choix2 => "antipationRetraite",
            $choix3 => "reductionFiscalite",
            $choix4 => "augmentationRendementEpargne",
            $choix5 => "constitutionCapital",
            $choix6 => "transmissionEnfant",
            $choix7 => "revenuComplementaire",

        ],

        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
    ];
}

/*
* Configuration de base d'un ChoiceType
* Permet d'avoir le choix en plusieurs proprositions (Max 5)
* L'utilisation de cette function peut servir quand il y a plusieurs choix à faire.
*
*/
public function getConfigurationResidence($label, $class, $choix1, $choix2, $choix3): array
{
    return [
        'label' => $label,
        'attr' =>[
            'class' => $class
        ],
        'choices' => [
            $choix1 => strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$choix1)),
            $choix2 => strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$choix2)),
            $choix3 => strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$choix3)),
        ],

        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false,
    ];
}

/*
* Configuration de base d'un ChoiceType
* Permet d'avoir le choix en plusieurs proprositions (Max 5)
* L'utilisation de cette function sert quand il y a plusieurs choix à faire.
*
*/
public function getConfigurationEpargne($label, $class, $choix1, $choix2, $choix3, $choix4, $choix5): array
{
    return [
        'label' => $label,
        'attr' =>[
            'class' => $class
        ],
        'choices' => [
            $choix1 => "10k",
            $choix2 => "20k",
            $choix3 => "50k",
            $choix4 => "100k",
            $choix5 => "1000k",
        ],

        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false,
    ];
}


/**
 * L'utilisation de cette fonction est unique (Partie 1)
 *
 * @param $label
 * @param $class
 * @return array
 */
private function getConfigurationChoice($label, $class): array
{
    return
        [
            'label' => $label,
            'attr' =>[
                'class' => $class
                ],
            'choices' => [
                'Célibataire' => 'celibataire',
                'Marié(e)' => 'marie',
                'Pacsé(e)' => 'pacse',
                'En concubinage' => 'concubinage',
                'Divorcé(e)' => 'divorce',
                'Veuf/Veuve' => 'veuf'
            ]
        ];
}
```

SimulationController

```
class SimulationController extends AbstractController

/**
 * @Route("/simulation", name="simulation")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param ObjectManager $manager
 * @return Response
 */
public function formulaire(Request $request, ObjectManager $manager)
{

    $Client = new Client();

    $form = $this->createForm(SimulationType::class, $Client); //SimulationType = Formulaire avec les champs


    /**
     * Permet d'agir en fonction des résultats des formulaires
     */
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    dump($Client);
    /* Est ce que le formulaire est bien valide ? */
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // Si la formulaire est correct --> Direction la page Patrimoine
        return $this->render('content/verification.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()]);

    } elseif ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() == false) {
        // Si la page n'est pas correct, il affiche la page de vérification
        return $this->render(
            '/content/verification.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()]);
    } else {
        return $this->render(
            '/content/simulation.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Render the fields, wrap them with a `div` or sthing. Show/hide the div with javascript

Comment: @DarkBee I have to put the fields in non-compulsory so don't I? Otherwise, no matter how much I hide them, it won't change anything.

Comment: You need to adjust the backend anyhow based on the first input even if you did this with ajax or not.

Answer (score 1):

You've to use Form Events to make your form element update if another form element is updated. That is quite complicated. On the [symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) you can find an example.